# Python string list printing with escape characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list variable, with a string in it. For some reason, it's printing like this:

```
print('Value = ' + str(var))
```

outputs:

```
Value = [\'123456789\']
```

It seems as if those are the escaped quote ticks added by the str function, but I don't know how to get rid of them.

**EDIT**: Sorry for the confusion. Here is the more complete back-story:

I'm writing a chat analytics app. Here's my Message class:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, name, text, likers):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.likers = likers

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Message: ' + self.name + ' said "' + self.text + '", liked by ' + str(self.likers)
```

This is where messages are stored:

```
message = data['response']['messages'][i]

user_id = message['user_id']
name = message['name']  # Sender
text = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str(message['text']))
likers = message['favorited_by']

msg = Message(name, text, likers)

users[user_id].messages.append(msg)
```

Above, `data` is a JSON returned from the chat server. `i` is my variable to loop through the messages (received in blocks of 20). `users` is a dictionary mapping user ID's to User objects (my other class). Since each message can be liked by multiple users, `likers` is an array of user ID's.

The problem arises when I'm trying to print messages. Test code:

```
print([str(x) for x in users[user_names['MyUser']].messages])
```

(`user_names` is a dictionary that maps usernames to user ID's)

That code prints:

```
['Message: MyUser said "all of you", liked by [\'25843278\']', 'Message: MyUser said "why?", liked by [\'25843278\']']
```

Comment: what is the value of var.

Comment: Can you show us what `var` contains?

Comment: It's highly likely that your string actually contains those backslashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `likers` is a list of string.

```
likers = ['25843278']
```

If you use `str`, Python will convert this list into a string, like this:

```
text = str(likers)
print(repr(text))
# -> "['25843278']"
```

So, your `__str__` method will return a string with single quote.

Further, you create a list of messages:

```
[str(x) for x in users[user_names['MyUser']].messages]
```

Python will print this list. It will convert each item to its string representation. So it will escape the single quotes of each likers.

To avoid this, you can convert the list of likers into a string yourself, like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ('Message: ' + self.name + ' said "' + self.text + '",
            liked by ' + ', '.join(self.likers))
```

Comment: Sure. I ran `print('likers = ' + str(likers))` right after creating `likers` and it shows `likers = ['25843278']`.

Comment: @user3284178: use `repr` function to print the string representation of variables, please.

Comment: Okay, `print('likers = ' + repr(message['favorited_by']))` prints the same thing: `likers = ['25843278']`.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the problem by replacing that line with `for msg in users[user_names['MyUser']].messages:
    print(msg)`